# Code to show browser local storage contents not working

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage

The javascript in the code below is not displaying the contents of the local storage as expected:

```
<script>
    window.open("https://www.cms.gov/medicare-coverage-database/search-results.aspx?keyword=memo&keywordType=starts&areaId=all&docType=NCA,NCD,F&contractOption=all&sortBy=relevance", "wf");

    showlocal();
    
    function showlocal()
    {
        alert(window.localStorage.length);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++)
        {
            key=window.localStorage.key(i);
            console.log(key+' => '+window.localStorage.getItem(key));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting? `window.open` doesn't grant you access to `cms.gov`'s local storage space.

Comment: When I open that URL, I can see the local storage (when I do a Inspect and view the Application tab), so why can't I see it with window.open?